# Read each line to match a pattern

Tags: if-statement, awk, while-loop, case

I have the following details in a input.txt file. My requirement is to match the patterns "Stopped|Aborted|isn't running" in any of the lines, need to print that line. And if the all are in "Running" state need to print a single message that "ALL ARE RUNNING".

```
SVRSVC1 SVRSVC1 NAME    SVRSVC1 PID     Running
SVRSVC2 SVRSVC2 NAME    SVRSVC2 PID     Running
SVRSVC3 SVRSVC3 NAME    SVRSVC3 PID     Running
SVRSVC4 SVRSVC4 NAME    SVRSVC4 PID     Running
SVRSVC5 SVRSVC5 NAME    SVRSVC5 PID     isn't running
SVRSVC6 SVRSVC6 NAME    SVRSVC6 PID     Running
SVRSVC7 SVRSVC7 NAME    SVRSVC7 PID     Running
SVRSVC8 SVRSVC8 NAME    SVRSVC8 PID     Aborted
SVRSVC9 SVRSVC9 NAME    SVRSVC9 PID     Running
SVRSVC10 SVRSVC10 NAME  SVRSVC10 PID    Running
SVRSVC11 SVRSVC11 NAME  SVRSVC11 PID    Running
SVRSVC12 SVRSVC12 NAME  SVRSVC12 PID    Stopped
SVRSVC13 SVRSVC13 NAME  SVRSVC13 PID    Running
SVRSVC14 SVRSVC14 NAME  SVRSVC14 PID    running
```

Here is code i have written but i would like to know if this is the right approach or any easiest way for this. ?

```
#set -x
RUNTIME=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
TOTAL_RUNSTAT=$(more input.txt | wc -l)
while read -r line; do
if [[ $line =~ Stopped|Aborted|"isn't running" ]]; then
 echo $line;
 elif [[ $line =~ Running ]]; then
  echo $line >> runstatuslog_$RUNTIME;
    if [[ `more runstatuslog_$RUNTIME | wc -l` =~ $TOTAL_RUNSTAT ]]; then
         echo "ALL SERVICES RUNNING";
    fi
fi
done < input.txt
```

Here is the expected output:

If found "Stopped|Aborted|isn't running" print the line.

```
SVRSVC5 SVRSVC5 NAME    SVRSVC5 PID     isn't running
SVRSVC8 SVRSVC8 NAME    SVRSVC8 PID     Aborted
SVRSVC12 SVRSVC12 NAME  SVRSVC12 PID    Stopped
```

if not found, check to see if all are running then, print message "ALL ARE RUNNING"

```
ALL ARE RUNNING.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you'd want to test for all of the nun-Running states. This will produce the output you asked for from that input:

```
$ awk '{lc=tolower($0)} lc~/isn\047t running$/ || lc!~/running$/{c++;print} END{if (!c) print "ALL ARE RUNNING"}' file
SVRSVC5 SVRSVC5 NAME    SVRSVC5 PID     isn't running
SVRSVC8 SVRSVC8 NAME    SVRSVC8 PID     Aborted
SVRSVC12 SVRSVC12 NAME  SVRSVC12 PID    Stopped
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: How to make this case insensitive because it matching "running"

Comment: I am getting the output as below. I want to treat "Running|running" as same.                                                                                                                    awk '!/Running$/{c++;print} END{if (!c) print "ALL ARE RUNNING"}' input_status3.txt
    SVRSVC5 SVRSVC5 NAME    SVRSVC5 PID     isn't running
    SVRSVC8 SVRSVC8 NAME    SVRSVC8 PID     Aborted
    SVRSVC12 SVRSVC12 NAME  SVRSVC12 PID    Stopped
    SVRSVC14 SVRSVC14 NAME  SVRSVC14 PID    running

Comment: its the blank space.

Answer (score 0):

**Using grep**

```
grep -E "Stopped$|Aborted$|isn't running$"
```

1. `-E` for extended regex
2. `$` is to mark the end of the line
3. `|` is for logical or

**Using sed**

```
sed -nE "/Stopped$|Aborted$|isn't running$/p" file
```

1. `-n` to supress the output
2. `/pattern/` is to process only lines that match the pattern
3. `p` command is to print the line

**Using awk**

```
awk '{if($NF != "Running"){i++;print}}
     END{if(i == 0){printf "All are running\n"}}' file
```

Here we check if the last field `$NF` is anything but "Running", if so execute the default action, ie print the record. This will not match the `running` in `isn't running` as the match is case sensitive.